# CLT for random variable with dependent realizations

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider the following problem:

We have a random variable $RV$ with $M$ characteristics, while these **characteristics are mutually dependent** (the sum of their realizations must be equal to $1$).

Let me ilustrate on example when we would have $M=2$ characteristics: then, $RV = \left[ a_1 ; a_2 \right]$ while it holds that $a1 + a2 = 1 \quad \&  \quad \forall a \geq 0$. Now, let's say we have also $n$ **independent participants**, each with their own values of $\boldsymbol{a}$, but still such that $a1 + a2 = 1 \quad \&  \quad \forall a \geq 0$. We could plot the empirical distribution function in $3D$ as such:

[image: distribution]

- **Would central limit theorem hold in this case?** If we increase the number of participants $n$, will we get Bell shape even though in one dimension less?
- **What about the multidimensional case?** If we have $RV = \left[ a_1 ; a_2 ; \dots ; a_M \right]$, it would be enough for single $a_i = 1$ which would cause all the other characteristics to be zero. In case of $M=3$, the realizations would be located on a plane etc for higher dimensions. Does this mean that the value of **probability density would be in this case measured on realizations in one dimension lower? Could the CLT still work?**

Comment: There is a multidimensional central limit theorem.  You get convergence to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution ,which may or may not be supported on a flat subspace of your $M$-dimensional space.

Comment: Remember that the Central Limit Theorem is a statement about the limiting distribution of the mean of the observations with suitable location and scale adjustments, not about the distribution of the observations themselves.  Clearly if you have $\sum a_i =1$ then this will remain the case for the means of the observations.

Comment: Thank you very much! If I understand it properly, it is not, in general, a problem that I measure the probability in $3D$, while the real density is only $2D$ object? To count a probability of realization of some range of values, would I have to use 1 integral or 2?